# MockK: no answer found because the mock is modified from outside

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, junit, mocking, mockk

Hello fellow developers,

i have a following problem:

Let's say I have a class called UseCaseX:

```
class UseCaseX (private val repository: Repository) {

    override suspend fun invoke(params: Unit?) = repository.call()

}
```

Now, this UseCaseX is used in a class ViewModel, like this:

```
    ...
    val result = async { useCaseX.invoke(null) }
    ...
```

Then I use MockK to mock the UseCaseX in a ViewModelTest, like this:

```
val useCaseX = mockk<UseCaseX>(relaxUnitFun = true)
```

And I get the following error:

```
io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for: UseCaseX(#7).invoke(null, continuation {})
at io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.defaultAnswer(MockKStub.kt:90)
at io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.answer(MockKStub.kt:42)
```

So obviously the `UseCaseX.invoke(params)` function gets extended during `async{}` with an additional parameter and there is no answer for it so far.

**Question:** how can I provide the answer for the mock in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `withContext(Dispatchers.Default)` instead of `async`. Should work!